# What is the purpose of the default keyword in this scene

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I saw a question, which looks like this:

```
public @interface Controller {

/**
 * The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name,
 * to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.
 * @return the suggested component name, if any
 */
String value() default "";
```

}

What is the default keyword, and the "" after default?

Comment: it is the default value if not specified during use

Comment: Yes , it's duplicated, but thank you very much anyway !

Answer (score 1):

[`Controller`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html) is an [annotation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/).

The annotations in Java might have properties and in your case your `@Controller` annotation has a (`String`) property called `value`.

When using the annotation you might omit setting a specific value for the property and then the default value will be used instead. For example:

```
@Controller //<-- here the value is `""`
public class SomeController { }

@Controller("other") //<-- but here value is set to "other"
public class OtherController { }
```

Comment: thank you! but why i can't find this feature in jls

Comment: There is it: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6